# Properties of Positive Semidefinite Matrices.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am looking to do some modeling involving matrices and a requirement is the matrices be positive semidefinite and complex. However, the modeling tool I'm using does not handle complex values well, so I have to break things into real and imaginary matrices. Since the sum has to be positive semidefinite, does each part have to be as well:

If $A$ is a positive semidefinite matrix and $A=B+iC$ where $B$ and $C$ contain real numbers, are $B$ and $C$ both positive semidefinite?

Answer (score 2):

If $A$ is Hermitian and $A=B+iC$ with $B$ and $C$ real, $B+iC=A=A^*=B^T-iC^T$ implies that $B$ is symmetric and $C$ is anti-symmetric. In addition, $x^*Ax\geq 0$ for all complex $x$ implies (by splitting $x$ again to real and imaginary parts) that
$$
\left(\begin{array}{rr}B&C\\-C&B\end{array}\right)
$$
is symmetric and positive semidefinite. Consequently, $B$ is a real positive semidefinite matrix.

See, e.g., [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1249617/prove-that-matrix-is-symmetric-and-positive-definite-given-the-fact-that-aib/1249757#1249757) for more details.